# Windsor Castle IoC, how to register IBaseService<TObject> to BaseService<TObject, TRepository>

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have something like this:

```
public interface IBaseService<TObject>

    public class BaseService<TObject, TRepository> : IBaseService<TObject> 
           where TRepository : IRepository<TObject>
```

I need to register BaseService To IBaseService
(the IRepository<> is registered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you **have to** do it like this you'd have to override `DefaultKernel.BuildCreationContext` (or something like that).

Generally what you're doing is not supported because it's wrong and vague. You're better of being explicit, and creating.

```
public class Service<TObject> : BaseService<TObject, IRepository<TObject>>
```